# JEditorPane: External resources aren't resolved

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I'm using a JEditorPane to display some HTML data, however any images that have a `src="..."` at another location / server isn't displayed. I am guessing that this is some kind of security constraint; my question is: can I display data from outside of the JEditorPanes URL and if so how?

[image]

If there aren't any ways of disabling this, what would be a better method of being able to resolve these external resources while displaying the HTML in an AWT/SWING environment?

Code:

```
File f = new File("index.html");
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane(f.toURI().toURL());
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jep);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(sp);
jep.setEditable(false);

frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setTitle(wpj.getParse().getTitle());
```

Thanks to Andrew Thompson for highlighting an error in my HTML code. I've updated the HTML which can now be found here: http://pastebin.com/EixG3WLH -- It appears that **any improperly formed HTML can cause the images to not appear.**

Comment: is image `src` content relative or absolute path?

Comment: Absolute path to http://another.server.tld

Comment: if this is so, can you show us the init code for JEditorPane ? There is more constructors, and some of them, aren't good to use with images and external resources and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I've updated the question with the init code for the JEditorPane. I'm sorry everything is a little abstract, let me know if I can clear up anything further.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9z8ywVNp -- Here's the HTML too, in case it helps.

Comment: now it's properly, and very good, laid question, but I cannot provide an aswer. good luck friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work fine here using a file based URL for the HTML and with the image at imgur.com.

[image: ForeignImageInPane]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;

class ForeignImageInPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                File f = new File("index.html");
                try {
                    JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane(f.toURI().toURL());

                    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jep);
                    sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,200));

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sp);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeiWi.png'>
</body>
</html>
```

What are the actual URLs of the images?

#### Update

It also seems to work with an URL taken directly from the HTML.  Vis.

```
<html>
<body>
<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Kit_shorts.svg/100px-Kit_shorts.svg.png'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See also the edit.  BTW - why does the HTML at paste bin start with `<td ..>`?  That is not valid HTML as posted, which might be the problem.

Comment: Cheers Andrew, there are still some issues with the output but the HTML seemed to be the issue. I've updated the question with source code and HTML to match. :-)

Comment: Follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361779/jeditorpane-html-layout-broken

Answer (score 2):

I've built a JFrame with a JEditorPane in my IDE and it works.
What I did different: the constructor was without URL parameter, and after frame.add(jep) I did `jep.setPage(url)`.

It looks like the content type in your code for the loaded page is text/plain isn't it?